# Reason for declaring a property as (strong, strong)

Tags: objective-c

I just got a large chunk of code that someone else have written. First I dismissed it as a typo but then noticed it in several other places as well.

The essentials is that the other programmer (not sure of his "skill level") declared some properties as

```
@property (strong, strong) NSObject *anObject;
```

The compiler does not complain so I was wondering if there is any reason for doing this or should I consider them all to be "typos"?

***(The project uses ARC)***

Comment: Maybe he just means that it is very strong, the same way a very long integer is declared long long.

Comment: @Monolo But the correct syntax is long dong silver, not long long. :-]

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Thought it was long long time; // ago in a galaxy far far away // :]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see no sense in doing so and am surprised that the compiler does not complain about that.

Comment: I will assume that there is no reason for declaring properties as "ultra-strong". Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @John Topley. I do not speak english very well, but will do my best.

Answer (score 1):

I think the developer miswrote it. Strong keyword increases the retain count by 1 so by 2 strongs maybe the dev thought to increase retain count by 2..

Comment: That is the craziest thing I have heard today :)